# container border round inside row in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I made some container, there is 2 container in one row. i try to make rounded border in each container using boxdecoration but seems like it cant place on here so i removed it. so anyone can help me to solve this.

- and another question, how to make width margin in a column?i want to add a bit space on left inside column, look into 'image what i want'.

[image from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etkcs.png) ||
[image what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMDDu.png)

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22),
                height: 100,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 140,
                      child: Material(
                        color: kMainColor, // button color
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.lightBlue[100], // splash color
                          onTap: () {}, // button pressed

                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/leaf.svg',
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              // icon
                              Text("Penanaman",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )), // text
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 140,
                      child: Material(
                        color: kMainColor, // button color
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.lightBlue[100], // splash color
                          onTap: () {}, // button pressed

                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/bug.svg',
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Text("Penyakit & Hama",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )), // text
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into Card? Try wrapping each container with Card:

```
  Card(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
       child: Container(...)
  )
```

Comment: i try to put this, and the edge border still flat

Comment: edit: i think it works, i just delete the material, just another question how to make space from left between icon and text inside column

Comment: Maybe try wrapping with Padding.